# Are truth tables a valid method to prove an iff statement?

Tags: differential-geometry, logic, soft-question, proof-writing

I recently had a homework assignment returned to me (for a Differential Geometry course, undergrad level) in which my instructor wrote "You cannot use truth tables to prove an if and only if statement". I used truth tables to prove two questions from O'Neill's "Elementary Differential Geometry (Revised 2nd Edition)": problem #2(a&b)  of Section 5.5 and problem #1 of section 5.6.

My question is as simple as the title. I only want to know if truth tables can or cannot be used to prove an if and only if statement. Most sources I've checked say you can, but at the same time, my instructor says you can't.

EDIT: Question: Prove a curve $\alpha$ in M is a straight line of R3 if and only if $\alpha$ is both geodesic and asymptotic.

My answer was: 
Statement 1: By definition, a curve $\alpha$ $\in$ M $\subset$R3 is asymptotic if $\alpha''$ is tangent to M, where S($\alpha$)=-U' and U$\cdot$ $\alpha''$=0 where U'$\cdot$$\alpha'$=0 if and only if U$\cdot$$\alpha''$=0.

Statement 2: By definition, a curve $\alpha$ $\in$ M $\subset$R3is geodesic if $\alpha''$ is always normal to M, and 2$\alpha'$$\cdot$$\alpha''$=0 implies $\alpha''$=0.

Statement 3: By definition, a curve $\alpha$ $\in$ M $\subset$R3 is a straight line iff and only iff $\alpha$(t)=p+tq, such that $\alpha'$=q and $\alpha''$=0.

my truth table showed (statement 1 AND statement 2), then staement 3 if and only if (statement 1 AND staement 2).

Comment: what do you mean by you used a truth table? did you just label a truth table with the four possible outcomes for an if and only if statement?

Comment: In propositional calculus? Yes. In predicate calculus? No. **Edit:** You should add the problem statement and your proof so people can better answer your question.

Comment: As someone who's been teaching differential geometry for almost 40 years, I can't imagine a truth table appearing as a proof in such a course. (Basically, outside of a mathematical logic class or an "introduction to proofs" course, I would not expect/allow truth tables.) What in the world are these exercises?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Problem 1 of Section 5.6 asked to prove curve alpha in M is a straight line of R3 iff alpha is both geodesic and asymptotic. I used the definitions of an asymptotic curve and geodesic curve (where the 2nd derivative of alpha equals zero in both cases) and used the truth table to show alpha double prime equals zero if and only if a line is straight in R3.

Comment: Truth table? OK, so from $k_n=k_g=0$ you deduce that $k=0$ so $\alpha'' = 0$. But now you use calculus (or a previous result) to show that $\alpha' = c$ is a constant vector, and hence ... And, conversely, if you start with a line, you show from a parametrization (or again, from a previous result in the course) that $\alpha'' = 0$ (or curvature = 0). I honestly don't get the truth tables here.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I can email you the pdf of my answers if you'd like. I honestly don't know how to post truth tables on here, and writing a truth table in script is...awkward, to say the least.

Comment: @Git Gud: I took your response to heart, and thought about it. I feel like my answer (posed in the edit) was taking the position of the statement/propositional logic (and that the question itself wasn't really asking for more than that). I looked into predicate calculus a bit (haven't seen any in classes yet), and couldn't see how I would need to break my statements down any further to ensure all of the definitions themselves were correct (we had already covered geodesics and asymptotic curves [and straight lines!] and defined them rigorously). Anyway, thanks for your reply. Made me think.

Answer (score 1):

Your set-up is valid, but the math falters a bit. Your final conclusion in (2) is incorrect. So the correct logic is this: $\alpha''=0$ if and only if its component normal to $M$ and its component tangent to $M$ are both $0$.

> (1) says $\alpha''$ is orthogonal to $U$ and (2) says $\alpha''$ is parallel to $U$. Thus, (1) *and* (2) is equivalent to $\alpha''=0$.

You don't need truth tables. Just logic and math in words. Your teacher may have complained that the key idea was unclear.

Comment: Ah. I thought statements one and two (and therefore three) showed that $\alpha''=0$ is trivially orthogonal (pointwise) to both the surface M and its unit normal U.  Also: My instructor simply wrote "you can't use truth tables to prove if and only if statements". There was no other complaint or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to show that $\phi$ is true iff $\psi$ is true. You can make a truth-table for the propositional letters occurring in either $\phi$ or $\psi$, and check whether $(\phi \equiv \psi)$ gets assigned $\top$ by all rows of the truth-table. If the equivalence between $\phi$ and $\psi$ is a truth of propositional logic, this decision procedure is guaranteed to succeed.

If, however, $(\phi \equiv \psi)$ is *not* a truth of propositional logic, but only follows from a set of axioms $\Gamma$, then you can show $\Gamma \rightarrow (\phi \equiv \psi)$ using truth-tables instead. This wouldn't be the best way of showing the equivalence of $\phi$ and $\psi$ given $\Gamma$, but it would work. From your comments I gather that this is exactly what you've done.

Comment: I tend toward "not the best way" in all things.

Answer (score 0):

There exist mathematical propositions which are currently undecided.  If a proof comes as required for a statement, one might claim that the default assumption lies in that such a proposition is currently undecided by the intended reader of the statement.  If so, then two-valued truth tables do NOT suffice, since you'd have to write out the truth tables in the case when the proposition is undecided.  This entails using at least a three-valued logic, but then you'll have to decided which operation you want to use for logical equivalence.  So, such a truth table won't show that the proposition holds true, because the definition of logical equivalence will get contested.

There also exists the problem that if you were to formalize everything here you'd end up needing quantifiers, and consequently truth tables might come as impossible to construct.